# How to REMOVE a .firebaserc file to start firebase init process again or RECOVER it

Tags: firebase, terminal, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to start over again the setup process for Cloud Functions however I get that there is already a .firebaserc document. Initially I did the whole process, and when I finished I couldn't see the documents so I deleted the folder thinking it was empty and can't recover it. So my question has two parts:

My question is:

1.) The terminal tells me I already have a document so, if I deleted the folder with the hidden file on it, how does it affect?
2.) How can I start over again the firebase init process with the same project?
3.) Would it be possible to find the .firebaserc file with the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I was having was that the first time I did the firebase init, I used SUDO, so the .firebaserc file was not seen on the desktop and I could not find it.

I managed to locate the file by using these commands in the terminal

1. cd ~
2. open .

After that i deleted all the files associated with firebase. Finally to do the whole process right this time. I created a folder in my desktop called firebase and in the terminal I referenced by using cd Desktop - cd firebase . And only after i was inside this folder I used the firebase init.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. It doesn't affect anything. The .firebaserc file describes the project it is associated to. By deleting the project directory, you will need to create a new one before running the firebase init command again.
2. If you are keeping the same project folder, you would need to delete the .firebaserc file and start over
3. Since it starts with a dot, it is a hidden file. You can use the `ls -la` command to list files including the hidden ones or you can use `locate .firebaserc`

Comment: I managed to find the file. It was at home level since I'd used the sudo firebase init the first time. That was the reason why I didn't find it in my desktop where I thought I had saved it! I used cd ~ then open _ and there it was. I deleted the document and was able to start again!

Comment: actually it was: 1.) cd ~ 2.) open .